# Simple curdate() subtraction operation returning inconsistent results

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT cases.case_id, cases.county_id, case_name, county.county_name, date_referral,
date_flag, auto_flag, sessions.date_entry, curdate() - date_flag AS days_overdue
FROM cases
INNER JOIN county ON cases.county_id = county.county_id
LEFT JOIN sessions ON cases.case_id = sessions.case_id
WHERE date_flag <= curdate( )
AND sessions.date_entry IS NULL
AND date_flag IS NOT NULL
AND auto_flag = "0"
AND status_id = "0"
ORDER BY cases.county_id, days_overdue DESC , case_id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here's an example result set:

```
13-1206-B   McC v Jac   2013-08-15  91
13-0951-B   Gen v Gen   2013-08-16  90
13-1160-B   Bla v Bur   2013-08-20  86
12-3048-B   Wor v Wor   2013-08-29  77
13-0903-B   Ben v Ben   2013-09-01  5
13-0500-B   Bru v Bru   2013-09-05  1
13-1238-B   Bal v Bal   2013-09-05  1
13-0135-B   TDA v Tan   2013-09-06  0
```

The columns are case_id (irrelevant), case_name (irrelevant), date_flag, and the result of the equation "curdate() - date_flag" as days_overdue.

As you can see, the results are pretty inconsistent. Today is 2013-09-06 and it has not been 91 days since 2013-08-15. It has not been 77 days since 2013-08-29. But it has been 5 days since 2013-09-01, and it has been 0 days since 2013-09-06. So the latter half of the results are correct but the former...I don't even know where it's getting those numbers from.

Any ideas what's going wrong with this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to operate with dates as with normal operands via subtraction `-` operator. MySQL will not handle that. You should use [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function:

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_flag) AS days_overdue
```

to get desired result (in days by default)